# HTML print second page with no page break?

Tags: html, css

My html code is having this problem that when I print out the second page, the top of this page has no break... here is a screenshot of print:

http://tinypic.com/r/ek5fe8/5

What I wish is that there is a break at second page, before the phone number: 765-446-8078

HTML code:

```
<div class="divTag">
            <h4 id="help-header">Planned Parenthood</h4>
            <p>964 Mezzanine Drive</p> 
            <p>Lafayette, IN 47905</p>
            <p><a href="tel:765-446-8078">765-446-8078</a></p>
            <p><a href="http://www.ppin.org">www.ppin.org</a></p>
        </div>
```

I already have a print.css, and I tried to fix this problem by writing something like:

```
.divTag p{
page-break-before:auto;
```

}

But It did not work... Could anyone give me some suggestions on this problem please? Thx ahead!!!

P.S: MAC OS, CHROME+FIREFOX+SAFARI have the same problem.

Comment: mind the limitations linked to page breaks, ie. not applicable on element located in floating elements

Comment: and read http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.divTag p {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

'auto' only inserts a printing page break if determined necessary by the browser.

Also, you may want to wrap that css like this:

```
@media print {
    .divTag p {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```

Or you can use this css:

```
@media print {
    .page-break { 
        display: block; 
        page-break-before: always; 
    }
}
```

And put the `.page-break` class on the element where you wish to have the break.

Comment: Yea I already tried this way. But this gonna do a page break on every paragraph so the outcome will become: one single paragraph + a huge page break in a single page(and there is nothing else)....